# Strange syntax error in simple CREATE TABLE command - PostgreSQL, MySQL, & SQLite

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite, create-table

I am getting a syntax error with PostgreSQL, MySQL, & SQLite that I don't understand.  It occurs when the same CREATE TABLE command is run from Python and as a Query in pgAdmin4 and MySQL WorkBench.  The same command works perfectly on SQL Server, using MS SQL Server Management Studio.

The command is:

```
create table asDataSpecs ( NumField1 integer, CharField1 char(30), CharField2 char(30) )
```

pgAdmin4 displays the error message:

```
LINE 1: ...e asDataSpecs ( NumField1 integer, CharField1 char(30), Char...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 62
```

MySQL generates an "Error Code: 1064" at the same point:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(30), CharField2 char(30) )' at line 1

PostgreSQL & MySQL understandably fail at the same point when this command is run in Python - as a .execute() on a cursor connected to the appropriate back-end and database.

SQLite (run using .execute() in the same Python program) produces an error presumably at the same point:
Failed 'Try' while attempting to create the 'asDataSpecs' table
near "(": syntax error

Why do PostgreSQL, MySQL, & SQLite accept the "integer" field, but reject the first "char" one - yet MS SQL Server runs it OK?

(I don't think it is a credentials issue, as I successfully used ODBC with the same credentials to create other tables in the same database - in all four backends.  I would expect different error messages, if credentials were the issue - and it should not accept the numeric field.)

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=a77109a1a3f4e3ca27ccf69aa67dc2c5), [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a77109a1a3f4e3ca27ccf69aa67dc2c5) and [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a77109a1a3f4e3ca27ccf69aa67dc2c5). Make sure you provide a [example] with emphasis on "reproducible". Check if you got any funky but invisible characters in there.

Comment: Thanks for this "sticky bit".  It seems like it might be due to funky characters.  After re-typing the "Char(" bits, it now works in pgAdmin4 and Workbench.  I'll now go back and do this in the Python program.  Hopefully that will now work too.

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the PostgreSQL "Don't_do_this" page.  There are a number of other useful tips on that page too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was it - funky hidden characters.  (There was some high-ASCII character instead of a normal space (ASCII 32) between the field name and data type.)

All platforms now work as expected, both in the Python program and the respective back-end management consoles.

For anyone who is interested, even NotePad++ displayed this as a space.  But basic Windows NotePad revealed the mystery.

Thanks again, "sticky bit".